# Setting a bool: One function with condition vs two separate functions

Tags: javascript, methods, architecture, boolean, semantics

Given the function:

```
function Foo() {
  this.state;
}
```

with `this.state` being a **boolean** triggering **different functions** when set depending on the value (true/false),
which one of the two following implementations is better (or common) and why?

**One function with condition**

```
this.setState = function(bool) {
  if(bool) {
    bar();
  }
  else {
    baz();
  }

  this.state = bool;
}
```

**Two separate functions**

```
this.stateTrue = function() {
  bar();

  this.state = true;
}

this.stateFalse = function() {
  baz();

  this.state = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **first** one because it follows DRY principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

I would just slightly modify it:

```
this.setState = function(bool) {
  bool ? bar() : baz();
  this.state = bool;
}
```

Always try to write less **redundant** code but don't compromise too much. Make it less but readable.

Comment: On the other hand... https://overreacted.io/the-wet-codebase/